# Value getting changed after end of function

Tags: c++, memory, local-variables

I am trying to set data which needs to be used in another file (layer) of the application. During debugging , I see that the value gets correctly set for the first time . But when I try to use this set variable after the function , the value is changed. I think the memory is getting released causing the variable to reset . Can anyone please help me with what I am trying to do.

```
void SetExpectedTabsData(_In_ PCWSTR tabUrls[], _In_ PCWSTR tabTitles[], _In_ UINT tabsCount, _In_ FakeCourier* courier)
{
    wchar_t jsonPerTab[256];
    wchar_t tabsDataJSON[c_jsonTabDataSize];
    // tabsDataJSON should be large enough to hold any data.
    StringCchPrintf(tabsDataJSON, c_jsonTabDataSize, L"\"tabs\":[");
    bool isActiveTab = true;
    // tabId starts from 1 and the tabIndex starts with 0. Manipulated the json string generation accordingly.
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i <= tabsCount; ++i)
    {
        StringCchPrintf(jsonPerTab, ARRAYSIZE(jsonPerTab), L"{\"id\":%i,\"index\":%i,\"windowId\":1,\"active\":%s,\"status\":\"complete\",\"title\":\"%s\",\"url\":\"%s\"}", i, (i - 1), isActiveTab ? L"true" : L"false", tabTitles[i - 1], tabUrls[i - 1]);
        StringCchCat(tabsDataJSON, c_jsonTabDataSize, jsonPerTab);
        isActiveTab = false;
        if (i != tabsCount)
        {
            StringCchCat(tabsDataJSON, c_jsonTabDataSize, L",");
        }
    }
    StringCchCat(tabsDataJSON, c_jsonTabDataSize, L"],");
    VERIFY_SUCCEEDED(courier->SetExpectedTabsData(tabsDataJSON));
}
```

The courier file where the data needs to be set is as

```
HRESULT FakeCourier::SetExpectedTabsData(_In_ wchar_t* tabsData)
{
  m_tabsData = tabsData;
  return S_OK;
}
```

Please suggest the correct approach to do this.

Comment: Can you please tell why this questoin was down voted ?

Answer (score 1):

The variable `tabsDataJSON` is local in the function `SetExpectedTabsData`, so it can be overwritten after finishing of this function. And since it can happen, it happens.

When you call `FakeCourier::SetExpectedTabsData(tabsDataJSON)`, this function just remembers pointer to that local variable `tabsDataJSON`. But right after finishing of the function `SetExpectedTabsData` this pointer becomes invalid.

To fix it you need to modify the function `FakeCourier::SetExpectedTabsData`: replace copying of the pointer be copying of the pointed data. Since your `m_tabsData` is a `wchar_t*`, just allocate this string and copy the data from `tabsData` into `m_tabsData` (read about [wcsncpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/wcsncpy/) and similar functions).

Try something like this:

```
HRESULT FakeCourier::SetExpectedTabsData(_In_ wchar_t* tabsData)
{
  const size_t len = wcslen(tabsData);
  if (m_tabsData)
    delete m_tabsData;
  m_tabsData = new wchar_t[len + 1];
  wcsncpy(m_tabsData, tabsData, len + 1);
  return S_OK;
}
```

And also you need to free this memory in the destructor of the `FakeCourier` (to avoid memory leak). And to initialize `m_tabsData` in the constructor (`m_tabsData = 0;`)

Comment: what can i do avoid it? If I allocate the memory, I unsure about when to free it .

Comment: What is `m_tabsData`? How do you define it?

Comment: it is a member variable to FakeCourier class of type     wchar_t* m_tabsData;